# Multi-purpose generic pointer array with optional type-checking

Tags: c, array, pointers

I've been using this data structure in my projects for a while and finally decided to clean it up a bit and publish it online, but first I'm posting it here for code review. (EDIT: It has now been published [on github](https://github.com/BareRose/parray) if anyone is interested.)

It's simply a dynamic array of void pointers with lots of different functions that allow it to be used for all kinds of purposes. In some ways, it's similar to Javascript's arrays as they can also be used as more than just arrays e.g. stacks or queues. The main benefit of this is that I only ever need the one `parray.h` instead of having to write a separate one for each purpose (e.g. a separate `pstack.h` and `pqueue.h` for stacks and queues respectively).

The basic parray works with void pointers, allowing it to contain pointers to any kind of data. As an optional extension, the `PARRAY_TYPED` macro can be used to enforce type-checking through generated wrapper-functions. Because it is only an extension and StackExchange doesn't format macros very well you may want to skip over the macro section when reading the code. All the important functionality (along with documentation in the form of comments) comes after it anyway.

The code below is in the form of a header-only library. Anyone unfamiliar with this can (roughly) think of everything before `#ifdef PARRAY_IMPLEMENTATION` as being the header file, and everything after as being the source file.

```
//include only once
#ifndef PARRAY_H
#define PARRAY_H

//process configuration
#ifdef PARRAY_STATIC
    #define PARRAY_IMPLEMENTATION
    #define PADEF static
#else //PARRAY_EXTERN
    #define PADEF extern
#endif

//macros
#define PARRAY_TYPED(TYPE, NAME, FUNC) \
    TYPE; struct NAME; \
    static struct NAME* FUNC##New () { \
        return (struct NAME*)parrayNew(); \
    } \
    static int FUNC##Length (struct NAME* parr) { \
        return parrayLength((struct parray*)parr); \
    } \
    static int FUNC##Set (struct NAME* parr, int ind, TYPE* ele) { \
        return parraySet((struct parray*)parr, ind, (void*)ele); \
    } \
    static int FUNC##IndexOf (struct NAME* parr, TYPE* ele) { \
        return parrayIndexOf((struct parray*)parr, (void*)ele); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##Get (struct NAME* parr, int ind) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayGet((struct parray*)parr, ind); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##GetFirst (struct NAME* parr) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayGetFirst((struct parray*)parr); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##GetLast (struct NAME* parr) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayGetLast((struct parray*)parr); \
    } \
    static void FUNC##Clear (struct NAME* parr) { \
        parrayClear((struct parray*)parr); \
    } \
    static void FUNC##Free (struct NAME* parr) { \
        parrayFree((struct parray*)parr); \
    } \
    static int FUNC##Push (struct NAME* parr, TYPE* ele) { \
        return parrayPush((struct parray*)parr, (void*)ele); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##Pop (struct NAME* parr) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayPop((struct parray*)parr); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##Dequeue (struct NAME* parr) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayDequeue((struct parray*)parr); \
    } \
    static int FUNC##FindIndex (struct NAME* parr, int(*comp)(const void*, const TYPE**), const void* key) { \
        return parrayFindIndex((struct parray*)parr, (int(*)(const void*, const void**))comp, key); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##FindElement (struct NAME* parr, int(*comp)(const void*, const TYPE**), const void* key) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayFindElement((struct parray*)parr, (int(*)(const void*, const void**))comp, key); \
    } \
    static void FUNC##SortInsert (struct NAME* parr, int(*comp)(const TYPE**, const TYPE**)) { \
        parraySortInsert((struct parray*)parr, (int(*)(const void**, const void**))comp); \
    } \
    static void FUNC##SortStandard (struct NAME* parr, int(*comp)(const TYPE**, const TYPE**)) { \
        parraySortStandard((struct parray*)parr, (int(*)(const void**, const void**))comp); \
    } \
    static int FUNC##Insert (struct NAME* parr, int ind, TYPE* ele) { \
        return parrayInsert((struct parray*)parr, ind, (void*)ele); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##Remove (struct NAME* parr, int ind) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayRemove((struct parray*)parr, ind); \
    } \
    static TYPE* FUNC##Ditch (struct NAME* parr, int ind) { \
        return (TYPE*)parrayDitch((struct parray*)parr, ind); \
    } \
    static int FUNC##Capacity (struct NAME* parr, int cap) { \
        return parrayCapacity((struct parray*)parr, cap); \
    }

//structs
struct parray; //forward declaration

//general functions
PADEF struct parray* parrayNew();
    //creates a new parray instance and returns a pointer to it
PADEF int parrayLength(struct parray*);
    //returns the current number of elements in the given parray
PADEF int parraySet(struct parray*, int, void*);
    //overwrites the element at given index in given parray with given value
    //returns the index the value was placed at, or -1 on failure
PADEF int parrayIndexOf(struct parray*, void*);
    //returns the index of given element in given parray, -1 if not found
PADEF void* parrayGet(struct parray*, int);
    //returns the element at the given index in given parray, or NULL on failure
PADEF void* parrayGetFirst(struct parray*);
    //returns the first element in the given parray, or NULL if empty
PADEF void* parrayGetLast(struct parray*);
    //returns the last element in the given parray, or NULL if empty
PADEF void parrayClear(struct parray*);
    //clears the given parray of all its elements
PADEF void parrayFree(struct parray*);
    //frees the given parray and all its internal data

//stack-like functions
PADEF int parrayPush(struct parray*, void*);
    //appends the given element to the end of the given parray and returns its index
PADEF void* parrayPop(struct parray*);
    //removes the last element in the given parray and returns it (NULL if empty)

//queue-like functions
PADEF void* parrayDequeue(struct parray*);
    //removes the first element in the given parray and returns it (NULL if empty)

//sort/search functions
PADEF int parrayFindIndex(struct parray*, int(*)(const void*, const void**), const void*);
    //returns the index of an element that evaluates as equal to given key according to given function
    //parray must be sorted for this function to work correctly, otherwise the result is undefined
PADEF void* parrayFindElement(struct parray*, int(*)(const void*, const void**), const void*);
    //returns an element that evaluates as equal to given key according to given comparison function
    //parray must be sorted for this function to work correctly, otherwise the result is undefined
PADEF void parraySortInsert(struct parray*, int(*)(const void**, const void**));
    //insertion sorts the elements in the given parray according to given comparison function
    //comparison function should return 1 if first argument is greater than second argument
    //0 if it is equal, and -1 if it is smaller, parray will be sorted smallest to greatest
PADEF void parraySortStandard(struct parray*, int(*)(const void**, const void**));
    //same as parraySortInsert but uses the C standard qsort function for sorting instead

//insert/remove functions
PADEF int parrayInsert(struct parray*, int, void*);
    //inserts the given element at the given index in given parray, shifting other elements forward
    //returns the index the element was placed at, or -1 on failure
PADEF void* parrayRemove(struct parray*, int);
    //removes and returns the element at given index while maintaining order of remaining elements
    //returns NULL if given index is outside the bounds of the parray
PADEF void* parrayDitch(struct parray*, int);
    //faster alternative to parrayRemove that doesn't maintain order of remaining elements

//memory-related functions
PADEF int parrayCapacity(struct parray*, int);
    //adjusts the internal capacity of the given parray to most closely match the given number of elements
    //returns the resulting capacity after resizing, which may not match what was requested

//implementation section
#ifdef PARRAY_IMPLEMENTATION

//includes
#include <stdlib.h> //memory allocation
#include <string.h> //memmove/memcpy

//structs
struct parray {
    int offset;
    int length;
    int capacity;
    void** data;
};

//general functions
PADEF struct parray* parrayNew () {
    //creates a new parray instance and returns a pointer to it
    struct parray* parr = malloc(sizeof(struct parray));
    parr->offset = parr->length = 0; parr->capacity = 8; //initial capacity of 8
    parr->data = malloc(sizeof(void*)*parr->capacity);
    //return
    return parr;
}
PADEF int parrayLength (struct parray* parr) {
    //returns the current number of elements in the given parray
    return parr->length;
}
PADEF int parraySet (struct parray* parr, int ind, void* ele) {
    //overwrites the element at given index in given parray with given value
    //returns the index the value was placed at, or -1 on failure
    if ((ind < 0)||(ind >= parr->length)) return -1;
    parr->data[parr->offset+ind] = ele;
    return ind;
}
PADEF int parrayIndexOf (struct parray* parr, void* ele) {
    //returns the index of given element in given parray, -1 if not found
    for (int i = 0; i < parr->length; i++)
        if (parr->data[parr->offset+i] == ele) return i;
    return -1;
}
PADEF void* parrayGet (struct parray* parr, int ind) {
    //returns the element at the given index in given parray, or NULL on failure
    if ((ind < 0)||(ind >= parr->length)) return NULL;
    return parr->data[parr->offset+ind];
}
PADEF void* parrayGetFirst (struct parray* parr) {
    //returns the first element in the given parray, or NULL if empty
    if (!parr->length) return NULL;
    return parr->data[parr->offset];
}
PADEF void* parrayGetLast (struct parray* parr) {
    //returns the last element in the given parray, or NULL if empty
    if (!parr->length) return NULL;
    return parr->data[parr->offset+parr->length-1];
}
PADEF void parrayClear (struct parray* parr) {
    //clears the given parray of all its elements
    parr->offset = parr->length = 0;
}
PADEF void parrayFree (struct parray* parr) {
    //frees the given parray and all its internal data
    free(parr->data); free(parr);
}

//stack-like functions
PADEF int parrayPush (struct parray* parr, void* ele) {
    //appends the given element to the end of the given parray and returns its index
    if (parr->offset+parr->length == parr->capacity)
        if (parr->offset >= parr->length) {
            //double the available capacity by offset reset
            memcpy(&parr->data[0], &parr->data[parr->offset], sizeof(void*)*parr->length);
            parr->offset = 0;
        } else {
            //double the available capacity by reallocation
            parr->data = realloc(parr->data, sizeof(void*)*(parr->capacity *= 2));
        }
    parr->data[parr->offset+parr->length] = ele;
    return parr->length++;
}
PADEF void* parrayPop (struct parray* parr) {
    //removes the last element in the given parray and returns it (NULL if empty)
    if (!parr->length) return NULL;
    parr->length--; //reduce length
    return parr->data[parr->offset+parr->length];
}

//queue-like functions
PADEF void* parrayDequeue (struct parray* parr) {
    //removes the first element in the given parray and returns it (NULL if empty)
    if (!parr->length) return NULL;
    parr->length--; //reduce length
    return parr->data[parr->offset++];
}

//sort/search functions
PADEF int parrayFindIndex (struct parray* parr, int(*comp)(const void*, const void**), const void* key) {
    //returns the index of an element that evaluates as equal to given value according to given function
    //parray must be sorted for this function to work correctly, otherwise the result is undefined
    void** res = bsearch(key, &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length, sizeof(void*), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))comp);
    if (!res) return -1; //element not found
    return (res - &parr->data[parr->offset])/(sizeof(void*));
}
PADEF void* parrayFindElement (struct parray* parr, int(*comp)(const void*, const void**), const void* key) {
    //returns an element that evaluates as equal to given value according to given comparison function
    //parray must be sorted for this function to work correctly, otherwise the result is undefined
    void** res = bsearch(key, &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length, sizeof(void*), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))comp);
    if (!res) return NULL; //element not found
    return *res;
}
PADEF void parraySortInsert (struct parray* parr, int(*comp)(const void**, const void**)) {
    //insertion sorts the elements in the given parray according to given comparison function
    //comparison function should return 1 if first argument is greater than second argument
    //0 if it is equal, and -1 if it is smaller, parray will be sorted smallest to greatest
    for (int j = 1; j < parr->length; j++)
        for (int i = parr->offset+j; (i > parr->offset)&&(comp((const void**)&parr->data[i-1], (const void**)&parr->data[i]) > 0); i--) {
            void* temp = parr->data[i];
            parr->data[i] = parr->data[i-1];
            parr->data[i-1] = temp;
        }
}
PADEF void parraySortStandard (struct parray* parr, int(*comp)(const void**, const void**)) {
    //same as parraySortInsert but uses the C standard qsort function for sorting instead
    qsort(&parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length, sizeof(void*), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))comp);
}

//insert/remove functions
PADEF int parrayInsert (struct parray* parr, int ind, void* ele) {
    //inserts the given element at the given index in given parray, shifting other elements forward
    //returns the index the element was placed at, or -1 on failure
    if ((ind < 0)||(ind >= parr->length)) return -1;
    if (parr->offset+parr->length == parr->capacity)
        if (parr->offset >= parr->length) {
            memcpy(&parr->data[0], &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length);
            parr->offset = 0;
        } else
            parr->data = realloc(parr->data, sizeof(void*)*(parr->capacity *= 2));
    memmove(&parr->data[parr->offset+ind+1], &parr->data[parr->offset+ind], sizeof(void*)*(parr->length-ind));
    parr->data[parr->offset+ind] = ele; parr->length++;
    return ind;
}
PADEF void* parrayRemove (struct parray* parr, int ind) {
    //removes and returns the element at given index while maintaining order of remaining elements
    //returns NULL if given index is outside the bounds of the parray
    if ((ind < 0)||(ind >= parr->length)) return NULL;
    void* ele = parr->data[parr->offset+ind]; parr->length--;
    memmove(&parr->data[parr->offset+ind], &parr->data[parr->offset+ind+1], sizeof(void*)*(parr->length-ind));
    return ele;
}
PADEF void* parrayDitch (struct parray* parr, int ind) {
    //faster alternative to parrayRemove that doesn't maintain order of remaining elements
    if ((ind < 0)||(ind >= parr->length)) return NULL;
    void* ele = parr->data[parr->offset+ind]; parr->data[parr->offset+ind] = parrayPop(parr);
    return ele;
}

//memory-related functions
PADEF int parrayCapacity (struct parray* parr, int cap) {
    //adjusts the internal capacity of the given parray to most closely match the given number of elements
    //returns the resulting capacity after resizing, which may not match what was requested
    if (cap < parr->length) cap = parr->length;
    if (parr->offset) {
        memmove(&parr->data[0], &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length);
        parr->offset = 0;
    }
    parr->data = realloc(parr->data, sizeof(void*)*(parr->capacity = cap));
    return parr->capacity;
}

#endif //PARRAY_IMPLEMENTATION
#endif //PARRAY_H
```

Comment: C provides type safety, just use it!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What are you talking about? If you want a generic pointer array there's nothing better than `void*` and if you don't there's `PARRAY_TYPED` which leverages C's type safety, I'm not sure I understand your objection.

Comment: Just take a look at what's implemented with [`inet_addr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr). There's no need for `void*` pointers as long you're able to avoid completely opaque pointers. If not, use handles, instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you misunderstand. Using `void*` _is the point_, giving you a generic pointer array that'll store any kind of pointer (even different kinds together), `PARRAY_TYPED` is then simply an extension ontop of that for when you want only one kind of pointer (e.g. `struct foo*` instead of `void*`).

Comment: "generic pointer" --> are you looking for only a "generic _objects_ pointer" or a true "generic pointer" which includes pointers to functions?

Comment: @chux Just generic as-in void pointers, so just for objects/data and not functions. `PARRAY_TYPED` then optionally allows you to get specific to just one type of pointer, e.g. only `struct foo*`.

Comment: What was the reason to use `int offset, length, capacity` instead of `size_t`? Is this   for small/median arrays and not large ones?

Comment: @chux Mostly just that `int` is the go-to integer type, I've honestly never used `size_t` for anything. Not sure an array with up to `INT_MAX` elements can really be called "median" considering pointers are 4-8 bytes and the data they point to is likely much larger. Should I be using `size_t`?

Comment: @Wingblade The C standard library tends to use `size_t` for array sizing and indexing - although exceptions exist.  `size_t` is more consistent with the overall design of C, yet those with strong other language experience like `int`.

Comment: @chux If I were to use `size_t` over `int` I would lose the ability to return `-1` as my error value for functions that return an index. I suppose I could use `SIZE_MAX` to indicate error but could get  confusing.

Comment: @Wingblade Note: If the function returns `size_t`, returning -1 and retuning `SIZE_MAX` return the same value.

Comment: @chux Technically yes because of underflow, however the actual number returned is different (-1 vs some really big positive number). With -1 it's clear that it's not a valid index, with `SIZE_MAX` it looks like a very big index.

Comment: Whether signed or unsigned, the caller has the obligation to explicitly check the "out_of_band" value (being a special value with magic meaning, as opposed to "out of bound" of the respective data type). Think in terms of the caller. Typically, when special "out of band" value is used to signal special condition, the caller must not chain function calls (except for a very small number of situations). The caller typically must: call the first function, check first return value, branch to handle special condition, if no special condition then call the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any form of container should use minimal resources when empty.  In `parrayNew()`, I recommend `parr->capacity = 0; parr->data = NULL;`
2. `parrayFree()`, like `free()` should tolerate `parrayFree(NULL)`.  Add `NULL` check.
3. `malloc()/realloc()` calls lack   `NULL` checks.
4. Rather than allocate to the sizeof a *type*, allocate to the sizeof of the *element*.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

   ```
   //parr->data = malloc(sizeof(void*)*parr->capacity);
   parr->data = malloc(sizeof *(parr->data) * parr->capacity);
   // or 
   parr->data = malloc(sizeof parr->data[0] * parr->capacity);
   ```
5. <strike>Bug? Test in `parraySet()/parrayGet()` looks wrong:</strike>  Hmm, I'll review later.

   ```
   // if ((ind < 0)||(ind >= parr->length)) return -1;
   if ((ind < 0)||((parr->offset+ind) >= parr->length)) return -1;
   parr->data[parr->offset+ind] = ele;
   ```
6. Questionable architecture: The below does not distinguish between returning `NULL` as a error condition and `NULL` as the value of `parr->data[parr->offset+ind]`.  This restricts use of this generic container.  Better to use an alternative to indicate range error.  Perhaps instead return the address of the element or pass in a destination parameter?

   ```
   if ((ind < 0)||(ind >= parr->length)) return NULL;
   return parr->data[parr->offset+ind];
   ```
7. Bug

   ```
   // memcpy(&parr->data[0], &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length);
   memcpy(&parr->data[0], &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length*sizeof parr->data[0]);
   ```
8. Do not recommend repeated comments.  Functions definitions repeat the comment of the function declarations. This eventually breaks down with maintenance.   Comment well the declaration and in the definition refer to the declaration comments.  Stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
9. For arithmetic compares, I prefer arithmetic operators rather than logical ones:

   ```
   // if (!parr->length) return NULL;
   if (parr->length <= 0) return NULL;
   ```
10. Lack of `{}` tends to incur maintenance problems.  Better to add them.

    ```
    // if (parr->offset+parr->length == parr->capacity)
    //          if (parr->offset >= parr->length) {
    //              memcpy(&parr->data[0], &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length);
    //              parr->offset = 0;
    //          } else
    //              parr->data = realloc(parr->data, sizeof(void*)*(parr->capacity *= 2));

    if (parr->offset+parr->length == parr->capacity) {
             if (parr->offset >= parr->length) {
                 memcpy(&parr->data[0], &parr->data[parr->offset], parr->length);
                 parr->offset = 0;
             } else
                 parr->data = realloc(parr->data, sizeof(void*)*(parr->capacity *= 2));
     }
    ```
11. For functions that do not change `struct parray`, add `const` to better convey codes intent and allow for some optimizations and wider application.

    ```
     // parrayGet (struct parray* parr, int ind) 
     parrayGet (const struct parray* parr, int ind)
    ```

Comment: Maybe more later, GTG.

Comment: 1, 2: Agree. 3: If more memory cannot be allocated, that's a fatal error and there's no alternative to just failing outright, is there? 4: Fair point. 6: Don't disagree, but not convinced by your alternative. Perhaps the solution is to think of values outside the actual array as empty space, for which `NULL` is an appropriate representation. 7: Good catch. 8: Strongly believe in DRY myself, disagree it applies to comments. Could see keeping comments only in definitions as this is single-file. 9, 10: Fair points, but down to subjective coding style. 11: Considered this myself, will change.

Comment: @Wingblade " there's no alternative to just failing outright, is there?" the 2 usually candidates are to 1) exit right away (maybe with a message) and 2) return to the calling code in a manner to let it know allocation failed and let the caller handle it.  Presently this code does neither.  A 3rd idea is to call an error handler that is re-definable by the user.  There is no "best" and it is highly case dependent.   OTOH, there are weak approaches including "nothing".

Comment: AFAIK C provides no facilities to exit with a message (no `throw "ERROR MESSAGE";`). Presently the code _does_ do an implicit form of option 1 as it (should) produce a crash through de-referencing the returned NULL pointer, and a crash is what you'd expect from most applications when RAM runs out (I have yet to see an application that _doesn't_ crash on OOM). Now it's not great, but a true "nothing" approach like returning without doing anything would be much worse and harder to debug.

Comment: @Wingblade "as it (should) produce a crash through de-referencing the returned NULL pointer" --> C does not specify this. De-referencing a `NULL` is _undefined behavior_.  On OOM, I'd expect an indication, as code is able to report (case specific) the OOM event and then exit, not crash.  "a crash is what you'd expect from most applications when RAM runs out" --> is not robust programming.  Code as you like but crashing is usually not acceptable when selling your application.

Comment: @Wingblade The only certain error  return indication is `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`and even this is not so informative nor useful.

Comment: I don't like the undefined behaviour either, yea. Calling `exit` from within a library is a big no-no aswell.  "Code as you like but crashing is usually not acceptable when selling your application." That's a bit harsh. Real-world applications do crash on OOM, and from the perspective of the end-user your proposed "exit with an error" might aswell be a crash (albeit one with a message, which the user may never see if it gets lots in a log file somewhere). Getting into semantics over "crash" vs "crash with message/log entry" probably isn't productive, so let's not. More to come.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74843/discussion-between-wingblade-and-chux).